# Button becomes blank(text) when Onclick method executed

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, onclicklistener

This is the xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="eBay Search"
    android:textSize="13pt"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000099"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

</TextView>


<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="Keyword:"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:layout_weight="2">
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/keyword"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="Price From:"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:layout_weight="2">
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/from"
            android:layout_width="0dp"

            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Price To:"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:layout_weight="2">
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/to"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sort By:"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:layout_weight="2">
        </TextView>


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sortby"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:prompt="@string/op1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:entries="@array/sortlist">
        </Spinner>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:id="@+id/Clear"
            android:onClick="clearForm"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
             />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            />

        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/keyerror"
    android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="7pt"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/priceerror"
    android:layout_marginTop="445dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="7pt"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    >
</TextView>
```

This is the mainactivity code which has onclicklistener method for the search button:

```
package com.example.hrishikesh.hw9;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.net.URLEncoder;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search);

    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                int error=0;

                EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.keyword);
                EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.from);
                EditText text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to);
                TextView keyerror = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.keyerror);
                TextView priceerror = (TextView)     findViewById(R.id.priceerror);
                String keyword = text1.getText().toString();
                String from = text2.getText().toString();
                String to = text3.getText().toString();
                String reg = "^[0-9]+$";

                if (keyword == null || keyword.length() < 1 ||     keyword.trim().length() < 1) {

                    keyerror.setText("Enter a valid keyword");
                    error=1;
                }
            else
                {
                    keyerror.setText("");
                    error=0;
                }


            if(to.matches(reg) || to.length()==0)
            {

            }
            else
            {

                priceerror.setText("Enter a valid positive number for maximum price");
                error=1;
            }


            if(from.matches(reg) || from.length()==0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                priceerror.setText("Enter a valid positive number for minimum price");
                error=1;
            }
            if(from.length()>0 && to.length()>0)
            if(Integer.parseInt(from) - Integer.parseInt(to)>=0){

                priceerror.setText("Minimum price has to be less than     maximum price");
                error=1;
            }


            }




    });


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void clearForm(View v){
    EditText text1 = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.keyword);
    EditText text2 = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.from);
    EditText text3 = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.to);

    if (text1 != null) text1.setText("");
    if (text2 != null) text2.setText("");
    if (text3 != null) text3.setText("");

    Spinner spin1 = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.sortby);

    spin1.setSelection(0);
}


public void validate(View v){



}

public void search(String keywords,int from,int to,String sortorder){
    String url;
    int i=0;
    url =   "http://hrishisaraf-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/";




}
}
```

Whenever the onclick method gets executed and an error is detected like the keyword being blank. The error text is set and the Search button becomes blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why but Setting the width to wrap_content solved the problem.